# Catchable fatal error

Tags: php

```
class ClassA {
  public function method_a (ClassB $b) {

      echo '<br>'.'method'.'<br>';
  }
}

class Wrong{}

$a = new ClassA;
$a->method_a(new Wrong);
echo 'done.';
```

**Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ClassA::method_a() must be an instance of ClassB, instance of Wrong given**

Но  если я добавлю

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if ( E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR===$errno ) {
    echo "'catched' catchable fatal error\n";
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Ошибка пропадает и (**важно!**) идет вызов метода!Почему идет вызов метода?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, bypass ошибки идет , просто return false нужно в писать в обработчик, или делать throw еxception